# Django Set Default as Subset of ManyToMany Model Field

Tags: django

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    project_assignments =  models.ManyToManyField('drawingManager.Project', default=SetDefaultProject(self,default_assignment))
    user =  models.OneToOneField(User)
    default_project

    def SetDefaultProject(self,default_assignment):
        if default_assignment:
            self.default_project = default_assignment
        else:
            self.default_project = #somehow choose newest project

    def __unicode__(self):
        admin_reference = self.user.first_name + self.user.last_name
        return admin_reference
```

I'm trying to achieve the following behavior.  When a user is added at least one project assignment is set at the default.  And they can later, through an options interface set their default to any of the subset of project_assignments.  But it's not clear to me when you can use Foreign Key and Many to Many Fields as just python code and when you can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're not understanding that ForeignKeys and ManyToManyFields return different things.

A ForeignKey is a one-to-many relationship, with the 'one' on the side that it's pointing to. That means that if you defined `default_project` as a ForeignKey, `self.default_project` returns a single `Project` instance which you can use and assign as any other instance.

However, a ManyToManyField - as the name implies - has "many" relationships on *both* sides. So `self.project_assignments` doesn't return a single instance, it returns a QuerySet, which is the way Django handles lists of instances retrieved from the database. So you can use `add` and `remove` to manipulate that list, or slice it to get a single instance.

For example, if you wanted to set the `default_project` FK to the first project in the project assignments list, you would do:

```
self.default_project = self.project_assignments.all()[0]
```

(although in real code you would have to guard against the probability that there are no assignments, so that would raise an IndexError).

Comment: Thanks that was my confusion.  I didn't realize that Many to Many field returned querysets.  So I can do something like self.default_project = self.project_assignments.order_by(-date_added)[0] assuming that Project has a field called date_added to get the most recent project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I undertsand what you mean by "it's not clear to me when you can use Foreign Key and Many to Many Fields as just python code", but your pseudo code would work with the following changes:

```
def SetDefaultProject(self,default_assignment):
    if default_assignment:
        self.project_assignments.add(default_assignment)
    else:
        self.project_assignments.add(self.project_assignments.latest('id'))
        # note: i don't know what your intent is, so please adapt to your needs
        # the key here is `MyModel.objects.latest('id')` to retrieve the latest object 
        # according to the field specified. 'id', 'date_created', etc.
```

PS: it's recommended to use lowercase names & underscores for method names (to not confuse them with `ClassNameFormatRecommendations`)

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: If I use this code, it will add as a new project_assignment default_assignment right?  Thanks for the style tip.